# WSO2 Identity Server Change Shared DB & Identity DB to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, wso2, wso2-identity-server

As per WSO2 IS Documentation
https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/deploy/change-to-mssql/

we changed confuragtion in /repository/conf/**deployment.toml** to change carbon DB to SQL Server

```
[database.identity_db]
type = "mssql"
hostname = "localhost\\SQLEXPRESS"
name = "WSO2_IDENTITY_DB"
username = "sa"
password = "P@ssw0rd"
port = "1433"

[database.shared_db]
type = "mssql"
hostname = "localhost\\SQLEXPRESS"
name = "WSO2_SHARED_DB"
username = "sa"
password = "P@ssw0rd"
port = "1433"
```

But we are facing the following exception

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target". ClientConnectionId:4fb732a2-d3a4-4c41-bf0a-47b43d715de5
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:3806)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1906)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:3329)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2950)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:2790)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1663)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1064)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:347)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:228)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:769)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:697)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:198)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:134)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.DatabaseUtil.getDBConnection(DatabaseUtil.java:1067)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.UserCoreUtil.persistDomain(UserCoreUtil.java:913)
    ... 34 more
```

After searching we found that need to add the following properties:

```
encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;
```

but it didn't work

Comment: Have you tried specifying the `encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;` options in a `jdbcUrl` property yet? Ref: [Connecting the database to the server](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.0.0/install-and-setup/install/installing-the-product/setting-up-mssql/#connecting-the-database-to-the-server).

Answer (score 1):

If you are:

- Only using WSO2 IS in a sandbox environment or in a local setup for evaluation/development or testing purposes.

And

- Don't want to trouble yourself with exporting and importing certificates.

you can just use the `url` config to specify the database URL and set the  `trustServerCertificate` property to `true`.

```
[database.identity_db]
type = "mssql"
name = "WSO2_IDENTITY_DB"
username = "sa"
password = "P@ssw0rd"
url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;"
```

**!!! Important !!!**

This should not be used in production environments since it will make IS bypass the validation of SSL/TLS certificates of the DB server, which would make the setup vulnerable to attacks such as [man-in-the-middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that you are missing the MSSQL certificate in the client's trustore. Hence try importing the MSSQL Public certificate to WSO2 trustore. Take a look at this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/configuring-the-client-for-ssl-encryption?view=sql-server-ver16#configuring-the-client-trust-store) for more details.

```
keytool -import -alias <alias> -keystore  $IS_HOME/repository/resources/security/client-trustore.jks -file mssql.cer
```